# Sort Items by Travel Time/Distance

Tags: bing-maps

I currently have an application that calculates the distance to other jobs from a selected job. At present I am using a `DbGeography` field in SQL and doing a distance calculation. Sorting results descending and taking the top 20.

I now have a requirement to convert this to use Bing Maps and rather than have "As the crow fles" distances, it will use proper travel distances. From what I can see, I am going to need to do some crazy transactions to make this work. I am rather inexperienced with Bing Maps API so I do hope someone will tell me I am wrong.

If I have a list of 500 jobs and a user selects one. To get the travel time/distance of the other jobs and then take the 20 closest, will I really need to send 499 transactions to the routing API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use the routing API, however you can use a trick to reduce the number of calls you make. The Bing Maps Routing API allows you to provide multiple waypoints (25) into a single route request. What you can do is create a route that goes from point A to B to A to C to A to D and so on for 12 locations. In the response you will end up with a bunch of route legs in an array. All the ones with an even index in the array will be the directions from A to another point. You can then grab the distances from just those route legs. This would turn your 500 API calls to about 42 calls.

You could optimize this further and precalculate the distances using the original method you were using and use that to filter the first 50 or 100 closest locations to then pass into the routing service. This would result in only having to make 5 to 10 requests.

Comment: Way to think outside the box to bridge a gap in functionality. Thanks very much